# Using re with rsplit

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract the names of all name servers from whois.com

This takes all but the last server:

```
name_servers = (re.split(re.compile('Name Server',re.I),info))[1:-1]
```

This is what I would like to do in order to get the last server (doesn't work):

```
name_servers_end = (info.rsplit(re.compile('Name Server', re.I).pattern, 1)[1]).splitlines()[0]
```

I understand that re.compile cannot be used within rsplit. Is there a regex alternative for rsplit? Or is there a  better way to achieve what I'm trying to do overall?

Example content from info string:

```
Domain Name: google.com
Registry Domain ID: 2138514_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.markmonitor.com
Registrar URL: http://www.markmonitor.com
Updated Date: 2015-06-12T10:38:52-0700
Creation Date: 1997-09-15T00:00:00-0700
Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2020-09-13T21:00:00-0700
Registrar: MarkMonitor, Inc.
Registrar IANA ID: 292
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: @markmonitor.com
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.2083895740
Domain Status: clientUpdateProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#clientUpdateProhibited)
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited)
Domain Status: clientDeleteProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#clientDeleteProhibited)
Domain Status: serverUpdateProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#serverUpdateProhibited)
Domain Status: serverTransferProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#serverTransferProhibited)
Domain Status: serverDeleteProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#serverDeleteProhibited)
Registry Registrant ID: 
Registrant Name: Dns Admin
Registrant Organization: Google Inc.
Registrant Street: Please contact @google.com, 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway
Registrant City: Mountain View
Registrant State/Province: CA
Registrant Postal Code: 94043
Registrant Country: US
Registrant Phone: +1.6502530000
Registrant Phone Ext: 
Registrant Fax: +1.6506188571
Registrant Fax Ext: 
Registrant Email: @google.com
Registry Admin ID: 
Admin Name: DNS Admin
Admin Organization: Google Inc.
Admin Street: 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway
Admin City: Mountain View
Admin State/Province: CA
Admin Postal Code: 94043
Admin Country: US
Admin Phone: +1.6506234000
Admin Phone Ext: 
Admin Fax: +1.6506188571
Admin Fax Ext: 
Admin Email: @google.com
Registry Tech ID: 
Tech Name: DNS Admin
Tech Organization: Google Inc.
Tech Street: 2400 E. Bayshore Pkwy
Tech City: Mountain View
Tech State/Province: CA
Tech Postal Code: 94043
Tech Country: US
Tech Phone: +1.6503300100
Tech Phone Ext: 
Tech Fax: +1.6506181499
Tech Fax Ext: 
Tech Email: @google.com
Name Server: ns4.google.com
Name Server: ns3.google.com
Name Server: ns1.google.com
Name Server: ns2.google.com
DNSSEC: unsigned
URL of the ICANN WHOIS Data Problem Reporting System: http://wdprs.internic.net/
>>> Last update of WHOIS database: 2017-09-06T06:29:02-0700 <<<

The Data in MarkMonitor.com's WHOIS database is provided by MarkMonitor.com for
information purposes, and to assist persons in obtaining information about or
related to a domain name registration record.  MarkMonitor.com does not guarantee
its accuracy.  By submitting a WHOIS query, you agree that you will use this Data
only for lawful purposes and that, under no circumstances will you use this Data to:
 (1) allow, enable, or otherwise support the transmission of mass unsolicited,
     commercial advertising or solicitations via e-mail (spam); or
 (2) enable high volume, automated, electronic processes that apply to
     MarkMonitor.com (or its systems).
MarkMonitor.com reserves the right to modify these terms at any time.
By submitting this query, you agree to abide by this policy.

MarkMonitor is the Global Leader in Online Brand Protection.

MarkMonitor Domain Management(TM)
MarkMonitor Brand Protection(TM)
MarkMonitor AntiPiracy(TM)
MarkMonitor AntiFraud(TM)
Professional and Managed Services

Visit MarkMonitor at http://www.markmonitor.com
Contact us at +1.8007459229
In Europe, at +44.02032062220

For more information on Whois status codes, please visit
 https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/epp-status-codes-2014-06-16-en
--
```

number of name servers is presumed unknown, and they Must be scraped using regex.

Comment: Can you please show the "info" string?

Comment: That's not really what I'm asking you. We need to know the *content* of this string, not its *definition*.

Comment: I am scraping whois.com/blahblah, the contents will depend upon which URL I am scraping.

Comment: An example of this content, then.

Comment: Can you also post an example of the output you are expecting from a successful scrape?  It will help posters to a more accurate solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to split anything, but to search lines starting with `"Name Server:"`.
The right tool is [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings.

Here is the regex I use. It looks for stuff that starts with `"Name Server:` and followed by multiple occurences of a non-breakline character.
The lookbehind expression (unfortunately no direct link, but go to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) and hit ctrl+f -> "lookbehind") `(?<=...)` says that I don't want that part in the results.

```
results = re.findall(r"(?<=Name Server: )[^\n]*", info)
```

Output:

```
['ns4.google.com', 'ns3.google.com', 'ns1.google.com', 'ns2.google.com']
```

Additionally, it's generally better to compile the regex before using it, because `re` will compile it anyway.
Compiling it beforehand and calling the functions as methods of it might save a lot of time in loops for example.
Here, it also allows you to specify flags, such as `re.IGNORECASE`:

```
regex = re.compile(r"(?<=Name Server: )[^\n]*", re.IGNORECASE)
results = regex.findall(info)
```

Although such flags could be passed to the functions as well:

```
results = re.findall(r"(?<=Name Server: )[^\n]*", info, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: Thanks. what I meant to add is that I need to include re.compile within any such expression to include non-case sensitive matches. How could I combine this?